# Black overlay disappears over UIImageView background when touched

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, storyboard

There is an issue I’m having with an overlay I’ve put on top of an UIImageView. I’ll link a video detailing the issue. Also, I’ve included a photo so you can see the hierarchy of my views for this issue.

Video : [Overlay Disappears](https://vimeo.com/266240572)

[image: Hierarchy]

Initially I created a black overlay programmatically and added it on top of the background image, but it disappeared whenever I touched it. So I then tried to create an encapsulating UIView and added all subviews (buttons, labels, profile photo) and then added that UIView on top of the background image, I set the color and alpha of the view to match the previous black overlay and the same thing happened. I even tried manipulating the zPosition of the subviews and still nothing.

I’m not really sure what else to try, I’ve been told putting subviews on top of a UIImageView isn’t good practice but I don’t know what else to try. Even the 2 buttons on each side of the profile picture lose their background (buttons are supposed to be circular with black background, doesn’t show either). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried setting userinteractionEnabled as false for image view when you try to add a Overlay through code ?

Comment: Yeah, just tried it again and it didn't work.

Comment: @Jumpman987 try adding `selectionStyle = .none` in `awakeFromNib` of `imageCell`

Comment: Thank you, it actually worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable `selection` in `storyboard` for the cell as shown below

[image]